# jQuery&PHP click function and unique id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Welcome
I searched on this forum the problem which I interested in but I couldn't found.

I have a php & html code:

$AdmID = $row['id']; // this is a id of admin get form mysql
echo'[x]';

I need a function which delete admins from a table. I know how I can do it with php, but I'd like do it without reload the page.
When I click on the [x] I wanna get an id of admin (the php while loop displays the 5 admins). Every admin have a [x] sign.
If id is a normal string e.g id="test", it will be easy:
$('test').click(function() {});

But I can't do it when the id is a var. I parsed the php var to js:
var x = '#'+'$AdmID;';

How should be a jQuery function?

Thank's for help

Comment: Are you trying to pass a php var in javascript?

Comment: Yes, but when I write $(x).click(); whole time function shows me the last id. (I have 5 id).

Answer (score 0):

Just create a hook for jQuery with the id:

```
<?php

if (@$_POST['action'] == "delete_admin") {
    // if successfully deleted from db
    echo json_encode(array("result"=>true));
    exit;
}

$admin = array(array("AdminId"=>1),array("AdminId"=>2));

echo "<table>";


foreach ($admin as $a) {
    echo '<tr>
            <td>Admin ' . $a["AdminId"] . '</td>
            <td><button type="button" delete-admin="' . $a["AdminId"] . '">[X]</button></td>
        </tr>';
}

echo "</table>";

?>

<script>

$('document').ready(function() {

    $('[delete-admin]').on('click',function() {
        var remove = $(this).parents('tr');
        var admin_id = $(this).val();

        $.post('index.php',{action: 'delete_admin', admin_id: admin_id},function(data) {
            if (data.result === true) {
                remove.hide();
            }
        },'json');
    });
});

</script>
```